# Xml Layout in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to display one of layout at run time based on some condition and called layout take hall area of parent layout.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="348dp"
    android:text=" "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutdesign1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayoutdesign"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/textaddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearlayoutdesign1"
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtadd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:hint=" Please wait for Location Trace..."/>

</FrameLayout>    
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textaddress"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1" >

</FrameLayout>



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/submitgreen" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearlayoutdesign1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/startgreen" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/recordstatus_imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/recording" />
```

...................

```
if(flag)
  linearLayout.addView(tableRow, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                            (tableRow.getLayoutParams().MATCH_PARENT, tableRow.getLayoutParams().MATCH_PARENT));
                else
  linearLayout.addView(tableRow, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                            (tableRow.getLayoutParams().WRAP_CONTENT, tableRow.getLayoutParams().WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: You can do two things .. 
1)write layout in xml and set visibility based on condition
2) Add layout dynamically based on condition

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a flexible UI, where you can replace fragments based on the necessary condition, you cannot achieve this just by using xml design, you'll also have to make use of the underlying java functionality.

To replace a fragment dynamically you'll have to

```
// Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

You can refer to the documentation for [flexible UI design here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)